# "Formatting help" and "Preview" links for all areas that support markdown

Tags: support, feature-request

I see that chat supports markdown (just like questions / answers / comments), but it also has a back-reference feature (:messagenumber). Is this documented anywhere? Even when using the GUI (the reply button), it's not entirely obvious how it works -- e.g. :messagenumber seems to include @user (besides causing the back-reference-highlighting behaviour)

In any case, it would be nice to have "formatting help" and "preview" links for all places where you can enter markdown formatting.

Answer (score 5):

All chat messages have a permalink, and at the end of that permalink is a specific number. That number is the one that is used in the :messagenumber feature. This does indeed mean that you can link to your own messages, though you will get pinged for it. There is also a very handy [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat) that displays this number at the right-hand side of the message. Another neat feature is that you can copy-paste the URL of a message into a message by itself and it will be One-box-quoted.

Comment: Great. Still, is the :messagenumber feature documented anywhere (in addition to this permalink number being the same as :messagenumber)? Also, I would still propose that "formatting help" and "preview" links next to all markdown-controlled text areas would make life easier for those who post.

Comment: Hm, perhaps this feature request might be better off on meta.SE?

Comment: Asking for the links would be better off on MSO, yes. As far as I know, the :messagenumber feature isn't documented anywhere; I merely figured it out on my own.

Comment: OK. I think it should be documented. And how do I move this to MSO?